# How to unlock read-only filesystem on OpenWRT router linux distribution?

Tags: filesystems, openwrt

I have installed minimal OpenWRT firmware on Linksys router.

When I try to modify some of the files withing `/etc/` directory for example `firewall.user` file by using command `vi firewall.user` it opens file in `read-only` attributes only.

How can I enable editing of files? The `chmod` command isn't accessible and my memory in router is very limited, therefore installing any extra resources is not an option.

Answer (score 5):

The filesystem is mounted read only, you need to change how it is mounted.

But most embedded system don't work that way, and in those cases you need to modify the image you flashed the device with so it is correct from the start.

Answer (score 2):

Well, in my case, I have installed OpenWRT into a SD card and plugged into a Raspberry PI 2. Immediately after the installation I got errors like that one:

```
Installing kmod-usb-net (3.18.23-1) to root...
Collected errors:
* wfopen: //usr/lib/opkg/info/libusb-1.0.control: Read-only file system.
```

I tried things like:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

with no success.

My solution was to flash again the SD card and than I was able to install packages and write into the disk with no trouble.

Comment: But RPI !== WRT54GL router which I believe I was using.

Comment: Obviously you have tried to re-install the firmware, right?

Comment: It's hard to remember what i did 5 years ago. but i'm sure i would not ask if i wouldn't try reinstalling or installing different versions.

Comment: Not sure. Nothing said in the question body about it.

Answer (score 1):

This often appears to be down to filesystem corruption. When the filesystem is mounted as read only it is possible to use the `fsck` filesystem check/repair tool - provided you have already installed it (e.g. for the ext2/3/4 based filesystems it is package `e2fsprogs`):

```
fsck /dev/sdb1
```

Alternatively if the image is stored on a micro/SD card/removable storage then you can plug it into another Linux box and run `fsck` to repair the filesystems so it can be mounted again. When you insert the micro/SD into the other Linux box check `dmesg` to find the device name (e.g. /dev/sdb1) and run `fsck` as above.